# SQL Server bind variables stored

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, bind

Is there a table in SQL Server where I can see the history of bind variables used (equivalent to `v$sql_bind_data` in Oracle)?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not have the concept of bind variables in the same way that Oracle does, and as far as I am aware there is no equivalent table.